# How to create an Observable which sends onNext event every few seconds say X and then onCompleted after Y seconds

Tags: system.reactive, rxjs

How do I create an Observable which sends onNext event every few seconds say X and then onCompleted after Y seconds. and may be onError too.

Comment: You question needs to be expanded. It's not clear what you're even asking.

Comment: I think I want function to keep sending onNext in interval of 5 secs then onCompleted. then another function which sends onNext but ends with onError. Because one function can't end with both onError and onCompleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send onCompleted once, and then your stream is basically ended. The same for onError

Answer (score 0):

```
    function everyXuntilY(x, y, bError) {
        var afterY = bError?  Rx.Observable.throw() : Rx.Observable.empty();
        return Rx.Observable.just(afterY).delay(y)
                .startWith(Rx.Observable.interval(x))
                .switch();
    }

    everyXuntilY(500,4400, false).subscribe(
        function (x) {
            console.log('Next: ', x);
        },
        function (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        },
        function () {
            console.log('Completed');
        }
    );
```

> and then onCompleted after Y seconds. and may be onError too.

Any Observable following the observable contract may fire **either *onComplete* or *onError* but not both**.